# nHibernate erroring when using order by, conditional projection and SetFirstResult() together

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

When using an order by, conditional projection and SetFirstResult() together in a query I get this error:

> Invalid index 4 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=4

In my experience, this error usually happens when you have one field mapped to two properties, as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553437/invalid-index-13-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-13). But it is not the case in this situation, the query works fine until, I pass a value greater than 0 to SetFirstResult().

[This bug](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2133) logged with Nhiberbate seems very simular, but it was fixed 2 years ago.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Here is a sample of the code:

```
var query = Session.CreateCriteria<KeepItem>(KeepAlias)
            .CreateAlias("Resource", ResourceAlias)
            .CreateAlias("Memory", MemoryAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);

// other code

 query.AddOrder
                    (
                        Order.Asc
                        (
                            Projections.Conditional
                            (
                                Restrictions.IsNull(MemoryAlias + ".MinDate"),
                                Projections.Conditional
                                (
                                    Restrictions.IsNull(ResourceAlias + ".MinDate"),
                                    Projections.Constant(DateTime.MaxValue),
                                    Projections.Property(ResourceAlias + ".MinDate")
                                ),
                                Projections.Property(MemoryAlias + ".MinDate")
                            )
                        )
                    );

//other code

 query.SetFirstResult(skip);
 query.SetMaxResults(take);
  return query.List<KeepItem>();
```